# How to print a conditional's literal expression in Python

Tags: python-2.7

In python, is there a way to print out what a conditional's expression was before it's evaluated? For example, say I have this:

`a = 1 == 0`

How can I retrieve `"1 == 0"`? Some things I've tried:

```
>>>print a
False
>>>print str(a)
False
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A only stores the result of `'1 == 0'`, and not the expression itself. If you want to store the string `'1 == 0'` you have to do:

```
a = '1 == 0'
```

You could then get the value of `1 == 0` by doing `eval(a)`, which would print `False`

From my console:

```
>>> a = '1 == 0'
>>> eval(a)
False
>>> a
'1 == 0'
>>> a = '1 == 1'
>>> eval(a)
True
```